# Plotly opens new tabs in the browser for each generated plot

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

i am trying to render a trading simulation with plotly. The problem is that I have to generate subplots in a loop but every time I call the function to show the subplots, a new tab is opened in the browser. Is it not possible to update subplots in the same tab or locally in the same window?

```
while True:
    ...
    self.last_obs = new_obs
    ...
    self.fig = make_subplots(rows=int(len(self.periods) / 2), cols=2)
    for i in range(1, len(self.periods) + 1):
        row = int(math.ceil(float(i) / 2))

        if i % 2 == 0:
            col = 2
        else:
            col = 1
        self.fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=self.last_obs[i - 1].index.tolist(),
                                          open=self.last_obs[i - 1]['Open'].tolist(),
                                          high=self.last_obs[i - 1]['High'].tolist(),
                                          low=self.last_obs[i - 1]['Low'].tolist(),
                                          close=self.last_obs[i - 1]['Close'].tolist()),
                           row=row, col=col)
     iplot(self.fig, filename='name.html')
```

Comment: In your sample code it looks like `iplot` is called outside of the loop, but is that also the case in your actual code? From the way you've described it it sounds like you call the plot function for each item in the loop. Simple adding traces inside a loop is totally fine, so the problem is in code you're not showing.

Comment: I've updated the sample code in order to explain it better